# How can I improve this query

Tags: mysql, query, performance, query-performance

I have the [following table](http://pastebin.com/Vu6vt5JV):

```
CREATE TABLE `twitter_relationships` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `source_twitter_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `target_twitter_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `relationship_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `status_change_date` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `source_and_target` (`user_id`,`source_twitter_id`,`target_twitter_id`),
  KEY `target_status_and_change_date_index` (`user_id`,`target_twitter_id`,`relationship_status`,`status_change_date`),
  KEY `user_id_index` (`user_id`,`status_change_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=116597775 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY HASH (user_id)
PARTITIONS 1000 */
```

This table is pretty big, ~150M records.

And I have the following query:

```
SELECT target_twitter_id 
 FROM `twitter_relationships` 
WHERE (`twitter_relationships`.`relationship_status` = ? 
   AND `twitter_relationships`.`user_id` = ? 
   AND `twitter_relationships`.`source_twitter_id` = ?) 
LIMIT ?, ?
```

Here is the [explain for this query](http://pastebin.com/Dk8X2bDY):

```
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: twitter_relationships
         type: ref
possible_keys: source_and_target,target_status_and_change_date_index,user_id_index
          key: source_and_target
      key_len: 12
          ref: const,const
         rows: 8560582
        Extra: Using where
```

Any ideas what I can do in the query or even in the table structure to speed this query up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, since you already have a UNIQUE index that contains the `user_id`, you should be able to get rid of the `id` field, and use the UNIQUE index as the PRIMARY KEY:

```
CREATE TABLE `twitter_relationships` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `source_twitter_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `target_twitter_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `relationship_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `status_change_date` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`source_twitter_id`,`target_twitter_id`),
  KEY `target_status_and_change_date_index`
    (`user_id`,`target_twitter_id`,`relationship_status`,`status_change_date`),
  KEY `user_id_index` (`user_id`,`status_change_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=116597775 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
PARTITION BY HASH (user_id) PARTITIONS 1000;
```

Unfortunately, while this removes an index, it may *increase* storage requirements, due to the way that InnoDB indexes data. See "How Secondary Indexes Relate to the Clustered Index" in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-table-and-index.html

Second, while the `source_and_target` index has two of the three fields in your WHERE clause, MySQL will have to do an additional read to find the `relationship_status`.

Therefore, to improve performance, create an index that includes all three fields in your WHERE clause:

```
CREATE INDEX user_source_status ON twitter_relationships
    (`user_id`,`source_twitter_id`,`relationship_status`);
```

Then, if MySQL doesn't use this index automatically, you can force using it, with:

```
SELECT target_twitter_id 
 FROM `twitter_relationships` FORCE INDEX (user_source_status)
WHERE (`twitter_relationships`.`user_id` = ? 
   AND `twitter_relationships`.`source_twitter_id` = ?
   AND `twitter_relationships`.`relationship_status` = ?) 
LIMIT ?, ?
```

Lastly, you're missing the `UNSIGNED` attribute on the `id`, `user_id`, `source_twitter_id`, and `target_twitter_id` fields. I'm guessing these fields will never store negative values, so it would make sense to make them `UNSIGNED`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, as for the user_id in the primary key, i think you need it since the table is partitioned by user_id

Comment: Good point. I updated my answer as a result.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your query is here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823685/when-should-i-use-a-composite-index

As far I can remember, order matters in indexing and your query has `where status, user_id, source_twitter_id`. You can change the order of query to use the index `source_and_target`.

hope this helps!

Comment: If all columns of an index are used in the `where` clause the order in the `where` clause or the index does not matter. If you only use some columns of the composite index, then the where clause should contain the leading columns of the index to make it usable. But still the order in the `where` clause does not matter.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for clarifying the ordering concept

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Does the order of fields in the WHERE and SELECT claues count?  (I mean, first WHERE, then SELECT.)

Comment: @deszo: no, it doesn't - at least no in experience. But then the MySQL optimizer isn't know for it's cleverness (it definitely does not matter in Oracle and PostgreSQL)